# Data is not inserted into database using windows application but not showing any error

Tags: asp.net

Button Click Code

```
    String cs = null;
    SqlConnection scon = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    private void btnOk_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
            String name = txtBoxName.Text.ToString();
            String mobile = txtBoxMobile.Text.ToString();
            String address = txtBoxAddress.Text.ToString();
            String ty = null;
            if (radioButtonCow.Checked)
            {
                ty = radioButtonCow.Text.ToString();
            }
            else {
                ty = radioButtonBuffalo.Text.ToString();
            }
            int n = 0;
            using(scon = new SqlConnection(cs)){
                scon.Open();
                String query = "insert into new_customer(name,mobile,address,type) 
           values('" + name + "','" + mobile + "','" + address + "','" + ty + "')";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, scon);
                n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        private void NewCustomer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        }
   }
```

When I run this application it runs successfully without showing any error but it doesn't insert any records in the table. The table has the fields id, name, mobile, address and type. `id` is a primary key and it's an identity field. All the other fields are of `varchar` type.

Why doesn't it insert data in the table?

Comment: You do not commit the query.

Answer (score 0):

You just pass your parameters in this way as i mentioned below,

```
 SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(cs);
 scon.Open();
 String query = "insert into new_customer values(@name,@mobile,@address,@type)";
 cmd = new SqlCommand(query, scon);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",mobile);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",address);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",ty);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 scon.Close();
```

Comment: still not able to insert

Answer (score 0):

try by wrap the type field as [type]

```
String query = "insert into new_customer(name,mobile,address,[type]) values('" + name + "','" + mobile + "','" + address + "','" + ty + "')";
```

Comment: still not able to insert